# Im looking for a query to produce multiples of a number

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
  SELECT TOP 10 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
  FROM sys.all_columns
```

Running that code im able to get a incrementing count shown below.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
...
```

im looking for a way to get multiples of a number, for example, 28

```
28
56
84
112
140
...
```

Comment: So... `SELECT TOP 10 28*ROW_NUMBER()`?

Comment: @juan 53 * 28 should be my last number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are using the same idea :

```
SELECT TOP 10 yourNumber * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
FROM sys.all_columns
```

It will give your number * 1, then your number * 2, ...

Comment: huh, didnt think of that one. ty

Comment: Yes, this sound good. I tought the problem was generate the numbers.

Comment: @lizzy81 If Juan's answer or mine helped you to solve your problem, do not forget to select one has good answer before moving on.

Comment: i was going to mark yours, but i had to wait 7 minutes. thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: Thank you. That way it also clarifies that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to generate a list of numbers

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33146869/3470178

```
SELECT 24 * I as multi
FROM (
        SELECT (ones.n + 10*tens.n) as i
        FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) ones(n),
             (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) tens(n)
        WHERE ones.n + 10*tens.n < 100 -- Your Limit
      ) T
ORDER BY multi
```