# Generate a row range based on "FromRange" "ToRange" field of each row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with following fields:
`DailyWork(ID, WorkerID, FromHour, ToHour)` assume that, all of the fields are of type `INT`.
This table needs to be expanded in a `T_SQL` statement to be part of a `JOIN`.
By **expand a row**, I mean, generate a hour for each number in range of `FromHour` and `ToHour`. and then join it with the rest of the statement.

**Example:**
Assume, I have another table like this: `Worker(ID, Name)`. and a simple `SELECT` statement would be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
Worker JOIN DailyWork ON Worker.ID = DailyWork.WorkerID
```

The result has columns similar to this: `WorkerID, Name, DailyWorkID, WorkerID, FromHour, ToHour`
But, what i need, has columns like this: `WorkerID, Name, Hour`.
In fact the range of `FromHour` and `ToHour` is expanded. and each individual hour placed in separate row, in `Hour` column.
Although i read a similar question [to generate a range of number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425546/how-to-generate-a-range-of-numbers-between-two-numbers-in-sql-server) , but it didn't really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution would be...

```
WITH [DayHours] AS (
    SELECT 1 AS [DayHour]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [DayHour] + 1 FROM [DayHours] WHERE [DayHour] + 1 <= 24
)
SELECT [Worker] 
JOIN [DayHours] ON [Worker].[FromHour] <= [DayHours].[DayHour]
            AND [Worker].[ToHour] >= [DayHours].[DayHour]
```

Answer (score 1):

I you start with a list of numbers, then this is pretty easy.  Often, the table `master.spt_values` is used for this purpose:

```
with nums as (
      select row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 as n
      from master.spt_values
     )
select dw.*, (dw.fromhour + nums.n) as specifichour
from dailywork dw join
     nums
     on dw.tohour >= dw.fromhour + nums.n;
```

The table `master.spt_values` generally has a few thousand rows at least.