# Get hour from datetime range SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I have table containing branch id and branch starttime and endtime

```
  BRANCHID   SHIFTID        STARTTIME               STOPTIME        
    1               1   1900-01-01 00:01:00.000 1900-01-01 23:58:00.000 
    4               4   1900-01-01 07:30:00.000 1900-01-01 18:00:00.000 
    5               5   1900-01-01 06:30:00.000 1900-01-01 19:00:00.000 
    6               6   1900-01-01 06:30:00.000 1900-01-01 17:00:00.000 
    7               7   1900-01-01 00:30:00.000 1900-01-01 18:00:00.000
```

Now i want to get the number of hours in date range like :

```
BRANCHID              Hours     
        1               1   
        1               2  
        1               3
        .               .
        .               .
```

The resultant table containing branch id and hours in time interval. like branch 1 start time is 00:01:00 - 23:58:00. Than branch id 1 time interval contains following hours 1,2,3,4,5,6 and so on..

Comment: please explain the result and tag the version of SQL server you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create temp table #hours.

```
create table #Hours
    (
    BId int,
    [Hour] int
    )
```

Get max and min datetime.

```
While (@minDateTime < @maxDateTime)
begin
   insert into #Hours values (@brID,Datepart(hour,@minDateTime))
   set @minDateTime = DATEADD(hh,1,@minDateTime)
end 

Select * from #Hours
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
branchid from table t1
cross apply
(
select n from numbers
where n >=datepart(hour,starttime) and n<=datepart(hour,stoptime)
) b
```

Below are some links on the numbers table used..

1.http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/

2.https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable

Comment: Never leave home without your numbers table

Comment: FYI | Great for a simple numbers table where you don't have `CREATE` permissions: [Generate a number sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425546/how-to-generate-a-range-of-numbers-between-two-numbers-in-sql-server). Just change the `SELECT` statement to a `SELECT * INTO #numbers`. This has helped on contract jobs where I only had basic rights.