# How to create a table with a column of values from 1 to 10?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'd like to create the following table using SQL and Redshift, but I'm unsure how to go about creating this sort of table from scratch

```
value
1   
2
3   
4   
5   
6   
7   
8   
9   
10
```

I've tried the following query based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425546/how-to-generate-a-range-of-numbers-between-two-numbers-in-sql-server)

```
SELECT ones.n + 10*tens.n + 1000
FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) ones(n),
     (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)                ) tens(n)
WHERE ones.n + 10*tens.n + 1000 BETWEEN 0 AND 10
```

But I get the following error:

```
syntax error at or near ","
  Position: 52
SELECT ones.n + 10*tens.n + 1000
FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) ones(n),
               ^
     (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)                ) tens(n)
```

Comment: Which version of sql?

Comment: For 10 rows I would simply run 10 Inserts.

Comment: it is because of the [unsupported features of redshift](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html)

Comment: `select * from generate_series(1,10)`

Comment: Are you wanting to actually store the results in a table, or are you generating a table purely for use within a query? The former works with `generate_series()`, the latter does not.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a table and then insert the data into it?

```
Create table t1(value int);
insert into t1 values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are ultimately trying to do, but you can always just do an inline view of union'd values if you need a single SELECT statement:

```
SELECT t.Number
FROM
(
    SELECT 0 AS Number UNION
    SELECT 1 AS Number UNION
    SELECT 2 AS Number UNION
    SELECT 3 AS Number UNION
    SELECT 4 AS Number UNION
    SELECT 5 AS Number UNION
    SELECT 6 AS Number UNION
    SELECT 7 AS Number UNION
    SELECT 8 AS Number
) AS t
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the official documentation from amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html), `VALUES list used as constant tables` are **not supported** on redshift.

As a workaround, you could either create your own, temporary table and insert the ten numbers, or use something like this:

```
SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 ...
```

Hint: Probably you can even generate large number tables, by using the known approach:

```
SELECT ones.n + 10*tens.n + 100*hundreds.n + 1000*thousands.n
FROM (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 ...) ones(n),
     (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 ...) tens(n),
     (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 ...) hundreds(n),
     (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 ...) thousands(n)
ORDER BY 1
```