# Create a sequence from the starting and ending values in a SQL Server 2008 table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sequence

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have a table `temp`:

```
select * from temp
```

returns this:

```
name    start_limit   end_limit
-------------------------------
j       2             7
t       1             9
```

Now I want a to generate the following sequence

```
name    allowed values
----------------------
j       2
j       3
j       4
j       5
j       6
j       7
t       1
t       2
t       3
t       4
t       5
t       6
t       7
t       8
t       9
```

What should I do?

Comment: This will probably help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425546/how-to-generate-a-range-of-numbers-between-two-numbers-in-sql-server

Answer (score 3):

This will work perfectly:

```
;with a as(
select name,start_limit as [allowed values] from temp
union all
select b.name,a.[allowed values]+1 as [allowed values] from temp b inner join a on b.name=a.name and b.end_limit>a.[allowed values]
)
select * from a order by name,seq;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way using *tally table* no recursion required

```
;WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
cteTally(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4)
SELECT a.name,c.N
FROM   ctetally c
       JOIN Yourtable a
         ON c.N BETWEEN a.start_limit AND a.end_limit
```