# FInd missing row based on Column data -MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, .net

I am currently working on a.Net web form solution which generates a brief service report for admins to monitor the services done by technicians.As of now , i am having some trouble in coming up with an efficient SQL (for MySQl) **which return data rows along with the missing rows based on the SertvicePrtNum , which is in order.**
For Example :- 
This is my raw data in the table :-

```
Id    ServiceRptNum  Customer_ID  Date of Service 
----  -------------  -----------  ---------------
1      1001              3        09/10/1997
2      1003              8        10/06/2005 
3      1005              1        21/02/2003
4      1007              7        1/06/2011
5      1010              4        4/11/2012
6      1002              2        16/01/2003
```

Here the **ServiceRptNum** , **1004** is  missing in the table. So i want the db to return the result as  : -

```
Id    ServiceRptNum  Customer_ID  Date of Service 
----  -------------  -----------  ---------------
1      1001              3        09/10/1997
2      1002              2        16/01/2003
3      1003              8        10/06/2005 
-      1004              -            - 
4      1005              1        21/02/2003
-      1006              -            -
5      1007              7        1/06/2011
-      1008              -            - 
-      1009              -            -
6      1010              4        4/11/2012
```

Here , the sql additionally generated  1004,1006,1008,1009 since it cannot find those records.

Please note that the Id is automatically generated (auto_increment)while insert of the data.But the Service ReportNum is not , this is to enable the admin to add the service report later on with the manually generated report Num (report num in the hardcopy of the company Servicebook).

Comment: You haven't made it easy for yourself by deciding there's two numbers between 1,007 and 10,010 rather than 9,002.

Comment: Corrected the Error

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect edits made to the post, refresh the page to see them

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to invent a constant, sequential stream of numbers and then left join your real data to them. For this method to work, you need a table with enough rows in it to generate a counter big enough:

```
select ID, 1000+n as servicerptnum, customer_id, `Date of Service` from
(
 SELECT  @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS n
 FROM    somebigtable 
 JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
 WHERE   @curRow<100
) numbergen
LEFT JOIN
tablewithmissingservicerptnum
ON
  servicerptnum = 1000+n
```

You need to alter some things in the code above because you never told us the name of your table with missing rptnums. You also need to utilise another table in your database with more rows than this table because the way this method works is to count the rows in the bigger table, giving each a number. If you don't have any table bigger than this one, we can probably get enough rows by cross joining a smaller table to itself or by using this table. Replace `somebigtable` with `thistable CROSS JOIN thistable` where this table is the name of the table with missing servicerptnums

If you want just the rows that are missing, add a `WHERE servicerptnum is null` to the end of the sql

Edit, I see you've changed your numbering from:

```
1001
1002
...
1009
10010
```

To:

```
1009
1010
```

The join condition used to be `servicerptnum = concat('100', cast(n as varchar))`, it is now `servicerptnum = 1000+n`..

Comment: The OP may be under the impression that this is something they *need* to do. But while it may be a solution, it's neither necessary nor particularly efficient.

Comment: Thanks @Caius Jard. The solution u provide is working except the part where I need to CROSS JOIN the table to itself. I am getting the error   --
 Not unique table/alias:"tablewithmissingservicerptnum" .

Comment: @Strawberry Yes. i am having some performance issues when i am doing all this heavylifting in the database layer. I will be doing some work around later on with the application layer if it cause much performance Issue. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @strawberry yes- typically people ask questions when they feel they need to do something but don't know what. My post mentions lots of things that "this" could refer to - would you care to be more specific?

Comment: @AswinArshad you can make it unique then... `sometable a CROSS JOIN sometable b`. Did you really have no table in your database with more rows than this one? No logging table or something?

Comment: @CaiusJard  Yes, I have. I will use it then.Thanks

Comment: A more accurate opening sentence might begin: "You could invent..."

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425546/how-to-generate-a-range-of-numbers-between-two-numbers-in-sql-server) for ideas on how to generate a group of continuous integers, then select from that left outer join your table. You should get a row for every number but all the values will be null for the missing numbers.