# SQL select numbers - dynamically with incrementing value in each row

Tags: sql-server, select, auto-increment, numeric

Is there a way to write a dynamic sql select statement (not query a table/column) that will return something like this

```
id
1
2
3
4
5
... 
etc.
```

I need to write several generic queries that pull values 1 through X 
(X will be pre-determined by a different query prior).

Say X is 5 the data will return 5 rows with 1 2 3 4 5 
 
if X is 27 the data will return 1 2 3 ... 27 and so on.

*on additional comment this is used in a third party sybase software and i am limited to the complexity of queries it seems creating and dropping tables doesn't seem to work*

Comment: in comments you've mentioned `third party sybase software` and `complexity of temp tables`; you may want to update your question with additional details as to your environment (eg, are you writing SQL Server T-SQL code that will be run on a remote Sybase ASE database, etc), to include various product names and versions; the more details we have the better ... otherwise we could waste time posting answers that won't be acceptable/doable in your environment

Comment: I'd also suggest you provide a more detailed example of how you plan to use those numbers; as currently worded, I can't tell if you want to use the numbers for inserts, deletes, updates, selects ... if you want to use them for join/SARG purposes ... if a `select`, why you can't do something like `select * from some_table where id between 1 and X`

Comment: This question indicates to me that `SArg` isn't going to be a term recognised by the Op.

Comment: one other question ... what are you expecting as the largest value for X?

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can use a tally table. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Or maybe all you need is ROW_NUMBER. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql

Comment: i couldn't use things this complex the data is going to third party sybse software and i can work with basic simple queries that is hwy i'm having a hard time (although thank you for the tip, i learned something new)

Comment: A tally table isn't complex.  It's by far the cleanest and simplest solution.  Create a table of numbers from 0 to <a usefully high value> and then use joins.  For example 0..86399 gives one entry for every second of the day.  or 0..1023 gives a table you can join against itself repeatedly to get useful and arbitrarily large ranges of values...  `SELECT * FROM dbo.numbers WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 27` is as simple as you'll ever get...

Answer (score 0):

You could try a recursive CTE like so

```
declare @mx integer=4

;with test as (
select 1 as id
union all
select id+1
from test
where id<@mx
)
select * from test
```

Comment: Might want to include `MAXRECURSION(0)` to prevent bumping into weird behaviour above 100.  And then explain the costs/issues that exist when you reach 32k and above...

Comment: Do be careful here...a cte used for counting is basically a loop. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Answer (score 0):

27 selects:

```
DECLARE @Count int = 1
DECLARE @MaxCount int = 27 -- Whatever your incoming max is

WHILE @Count <= @MaxCount
BEGIN
SELECT @Count

SELECT @Count = @Count + 1
END
```

One select:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPNUMS (AUTONUM INT IDENTITY (1,1), GHOSTVAL VARCHAR(1))


DECLARE @Count int = 1
DECLARE @MaxCount int = 27 -- Whatever your incoming max is

WHILE @Count <= @MaxCount
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #TEMPNUMS (GHOSTVAL)
SELECT ''

SELECT @Count = @Count + 1
END

SELECT AUTONUM FROM #TEMPNUMS

DROP TABLE #TEMPNUMS
```

Comment: I can't tell if you want 27 single selects or one select with 27 rows.  Both answers included.

Comment: 1 select with 27 rows.

Comment: Updated answer with one select.

Comment: this will be in a third party application and i have to confirm if the complexity of temp tables will be supported.

Comment: You should still upvote answer's that answer your original question, even if you find new information that makes them invalid :)

Comment: Added another answer that accommodates the new information provided.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use CTE like this?

```
WITH OrderedRows (ROWN)
AS (
    SELECT 1 AS ROWN

    UNION ALL

    SELECT r.ROWN + 1 AS ROWN
    FROM OrderedRows r
    WHERE r.ROWN < 100
    )
SELECT *
FROM OrderedRows
```

Comment: Might want to include `MAXRECURSION(0)` to prevent bumping into weird behaviour above 100.  And then explain the costs/issues that exist when you reach 32k and above...

Comment: Also, it's better if you start with two values (0 and 1) and then start joining the table against itself *(each level of recursion doubling the range you're working with, giving much higher ranges and much better scaling)*.

Comment: Do be careful here...a cte used for counting is basically a loop. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your max number isn't ever going to be greater than 9999.  If it is then you will need to restructure the query to add another layer.

```
DECLARE @MaxCount int = 27 -- Whatever your incoming max is

SELECT ones.n + 10*tens.n + 100*hundreds.n + 1000*thousands.n
FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) ones(n),
     (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) tens(n),
     (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) hundreds(n),
     (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) thousands(n)
     where ones.n + 10*tens.n + 100*hundreds.n + 1000*thousands.n between 1 and @MaxCount
ORDER BY 1
```

See this answer on another similar question: [How to generate a range of numbers between two numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425546/how-to-generate-a-range-of-numbers-between-two-numbers)

Comment: Just to avoid repeating yourself, you could have something like `WITH ten AS SELECT * FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) ones(n)) SELECT blah FROM ten ones CROSS JOIN ten tens CROSS JOIN ten hundreds blahblahblah...`