# Aggregate event log to weekly overview

Tags: sql, teradata

Suppose I have the following table:

```
Table A: Event Log

ID        Step        WeekArrived        WeekCompleted
-------------------------------------------------------
1         A           1                  1
1         B           1                  3
2         B           3                  3
```

So in week 1, case 1 arrives. For this case, step A is completed in week 1, but step B is not. Step B is completed in week 3. Case 2 also arrives in week 3, and step B is completed in the same week (Step A wasn't needed for this case).

I would like to aggregate this event log into a weekly per step overview like this:

```
Table B: Weekly Overview

Week      Step        In                 Backlog               Out
------------------------------------------------------------------
1         A           1                  0                     1
1         B           1                  1                     0
2         A           0                  0                     0
2         B           0                  1                     0
3         A           0                  0                     0
3         B           1                  0                     2
```

For each week X and step Y, this table shows:

- In: the number of cases that started step Y in week X
- Backlog: the number of cases which arrived at step Y in week <= X, and are not yet completed at the end of week X.
- Out: the number of cases that completed step Y in week X

How can I get from table A to table B?

Comment: I'm using teradata, thank you for your comment!

Comment: What are the actual data types of `WeekArrived`and `WeekCompleted`?

Comment: They are both INTs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need a way to get a list of week_ids, I used Teradata's system calendar. Then it's a Cross Join plus some conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT week_id, step,
   Sum(CASE WHEN week_id = WeekArrived THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "in",
   Sum(CASE WHEN week_id >= WeekArrived AND week_id < WeekCompleted THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "backlog",
   Sum(CASE WHEN week_id = WeekCompleted THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "out"
FROM
 ( -- get a lsit of week ids
   SELECT day_of_calendar AS week_id
   FROM sys_calendar.CALENDAR
   WHERE week_id
   -- calculate the range of week ids
   BETWEEN (SELECT Min(WeekArrived) FROM event_log)
       AND (SELECT Max(WeekCompleted) FROM event_log)
 ) AS weeks
CROSS JOIN
 (
   SELECT  *
   FROM event_log
 ) AS steps
GROUP BY week_id, step
ORDER BY week_id, step
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a list of weeks so you can evaluate if there is data on that week.

in sql server for example something like this [How to generate a range of numbers between two numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425546/how-to-generate-a-range-of-numbers-between-two-numbers)

Then you join with your steps. Will work better if you have a separated table for steps too.

```
SELECT weeks.week_id, steps.step, 
       CASE WHEN s_in.WeekArrived IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as step_in,
       CASE WHEN s_completed.WeekCompleted IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as step_out,
       CASE WHEN s_pending.WeekArrived IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as step_pending
FROM weeks
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT step
            FROM event_log) as steps

LEFT JOIN event_Log as s_in
  ON weeeks.week_id = e.WeekArrived
 AND steps.step = e.step

LEFT JOIN event_Log as s_completed
  ON weeeks.week_id = e.WeekCompleted
 AND steps.step = e.step

LEFT JOIN event_Log as s_pending
  ON weeeks.week_id > e.WeekArrived
 AND weeeks.week_id < e.WeekCompleted
 AND steps.step = e.step
```

NOTE: Dont know what `back log` is.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look! For week X and step Y, backlog should contain the number of cases which arrived at step Y in week <= X, and are not yet completed in week X.

Comment: I add another join for backlog, but not sure about the logic. Please double check.

Comment: I change the table alias because conflict with the field names.