# SQL Stored Procedure with Input parameters with While loop

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, while-loop, triggers, do-while

I have a code below that should insert records into the table but unfortunately this code foes not work in case multiple records are inserted or updated or deleted. How should I rewrite the code for procedure to loop through all the inserted / deleted records? And I do need to use that stored procedure with Input parameters (not just simple insert into ... select ... from ...)

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyDB.sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MyTable_DEL_UPD_INS]'))
    DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[MyTable_DEL_UPD_INS]
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[MyTable_DEL_UPD_INS]
ON [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable] 
AFTER DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT
NOT FOR REPLICATION
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PKId INT, 
            @Code VARCHAR(5), 
            @AuditType VARCHAR(10)

    SET @Code = 'TEST'

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted d)
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted i) 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT TOP 1 
            @PKId = d.[MyTable_PK],
            @AuditType = 'DELETE' 
        FROM 
            deleted d WITH (NOLOCK)

        IF @PKId IS NOT NULL 
           AND @Code IS NOT NULL 
            EXEC MyDB.[dbo].[SP_Audit] @PKId, @Code, @AuditType 
    END

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted d)
        AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted i) 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT TOP 1 
            @PKId = d.[MyTable_PK],
            @AuditType = 'UPDATE' 
        FROM 
            deleted d WITH (NOLOCK)

        IF @PKId IS NOT NULL 
           AND @Code IS NOT NULL 
            EXEC MyDB.[dbo].[SP_Audit] @PKId, @Code, @AuditType 
    END

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted d)
        AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted i) 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT TOP 1 
            @PKId = d.[MyTable_PK],
            @AuditType = 'INSERT' 
        FROM 
            deleted d WITH (NOLOCK)

        IF @PKId IS NOT NULL 
           AND @Code IS NOT NULL 
            EXEC MyDB.[dbo].[SP_Audit] @PKId, @Code, @AuditType 
    END
END 
GO

ALTER TABLE [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable] ENABLE TRIGGER [MyTable_DEL_UPD_INS]
```

Comment: Can you modify SP_Audit to accept a table value?

Comment: Having a loop in a trigger is just like a really bad idea. it's going to affect performance awfully. Add that to the fact that you have an SP that, as it currently stands, is going to need a further loop to be able to use (so that for multiple rows, you loop through each one), you end up with a simple `INSERT` containing 100 or so rows requiring a huge amount of resource. What is the SP_Audit doing? Can you provide the SQL for it? If you have to use it, it may mean you're going to need to change it; which means you might need to change everything that references it...

Comment: Also, `WITH (NOLOCK)` isn't going to achieve anything in your trigger. In fact, I suggest you remove it; as it's more likely to cause problems than solve anything.

Comment: I do agree with you! Performance would be awfully. Th SP is simply does Select Into... Insert ... From ... and nothing else :). I would probably try to convince me teammate to give up on using the SP. He was so much eager to use that as in his opinion it's elegant...

Comment: Good comment on WITH (NOLOCK) usage. In my company they put that everywhere even on CTEs and Temp tables. Do not see any point of it... I would arguably agree that on a physical object it would make more sense.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using loops in triggers.
Triggers should be as quick to run as possible, since SQL Server will not return control to whatever statement that fired the trigger [until the trigger is completed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201266/is-it-possible-to-get-output-result-set-from-sql-server-stored-procedure-before)

So instead of a loop, you should modify your `SP_Audit` procedure to work with multiple records instead of a single one.
usually, this is easily be done using a table valued parameter.
If you could post the `SP_Audit` as well, we could give you a complete solution.
Since you didn't post it, you can use these guidelines as a start:

First, you create a user defined table type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.Ids AS TABLE
(
    Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)

GO
```

Then, you create the procedure to use it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[STP_Audit_MultipleRecords]
(
    @IDs dbo.Ids readonly, 
    @Code CHAR(4), 
    @AuditType CHAR(6)
)
AS
-- Implementation here
GO
```

Last, your write your trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[MyTable_DEL_UPD_INS]
ON [MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable] 
AFTER DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT
NOT FOR REPLICATION
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @HasDeleted bit = 0, 
            @HasInserted bit = 0,
            @AuditType CHAR(6),
            @Code CHAR(4)

    SET @Code = 'TEST'

    DECLARE @IDs as dbo.Ids

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted d)
        SET @HasDeleted = 1

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted i) 
        SET @HasInserted = 1


    IF @HasDeleted = 1 
    BEGIN
        IF @HasInserted = 1
        BEGIN
             SET @AuditType = 'UPDATE' 
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @AuditType = 'DELETE' 
        END
    END
    ELSE
    IF @HasInserted = 1
        BEGIN
            SET @AuditType = 'INSERT' 
        END

    INSERT INTO @IDs (Id)
    SELECT [MyTable_PK]
    FROM inserted
    UNION 
    SELECT [MyTable_PK]
    FROM deleted 

    EXEC [dbo].[STP_Audit_MultipleRecords] @IDs, @Code, @AuditType 

END 
GO
```

Notes:

- The `@HasDeleted` and `@HasInserted` variables are to allow you to only execute the `EXISTS` query once for every procedure.
- Getting the primary key values from the `deleted` and `inserted` table is done using a single `union` query. Since `union` eliminates duplicate values, you can write this query just once. If you want to, you can write a different query for each audit type, but then you will have to repeat the same query 3 times (with different tables)
- I've changed the data types of your `@code` and `@AuditType` variables to `char`, since they have a fixed length.