# Rows generation without loops

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, data-generation

Microsoft showed quite interesting demo (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oEpJB87Xg9U), where they generate 5 million rows for an empty table

[image: screenshot]

As I can see there are no loops or references to other tables with 5 million rows. I would expect 10 rows here. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FROM` clause is using the old-style join syntax with the `a` CTE specified 9 times. This is effectively a `CROSS JOIN` cartesian product of the 10-row CTE so that 10*10*10*10*10*10*10*10*10 rows are generated but only 5000000 are returned due to the `TOP` clause.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48776162/efficient-way-to-generate-2-billion-rows-in-sql-server-2014-developer) for an example of this technique using the newer `CROSS JOIN` syntax, which generated 2 billion rows in about 6 minutes on my box.