# How do I list the months for the last 10 years starting from the current month in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I list the months for the last 10 years starting from the current month using SELECT statement?

I can list all the current months since the last 10 years but could not list all the 12 subsequent months in the years

```
select top 10 dateadd(year, -1*row_number() over (order by name)+1, convert (varchar, getdate(),112)) as y
from sys.objects
```

will give me the last 10 years from the current month

202403...201503

```
select top 12 dateadd(MM, -1*row_number() over (order by name)+1, convert (varchar, getdate(),112)) as m
from sys.objects
```

will give me the last 12 month from today

But how do I merge the 2 statements above to get all the months from the last 10 years from the current month?

Please advise.

Comment: Use a calendar table. If you don't have one, invest the time to create one, they are **invaluable**. Then your question is simply "How to get the date for month that started 10 years ago", which i suspect you can easily answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just one option using a ad-hoc tally/numbers table

```
Select N
      ,YrMth = format(dateadd(month,-N,getdate()),'yyyyMM')
 From  (
        Select Top (121) N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
         From  sys.objects
      ) B
```

**Results**

```
N   YrMth
0   202403
1   202402
2   202401
3   202312
4   202311
5   202310
6   202309
...
118 201405
119 201404
120 201403
```

Comment: That's a very elegant solution!! Thank you!!

Comment: @user1205746 You were almost there  :)

Comment: Your solution is elegant and easy to understand.. Your assistance is much appreciated! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Use CTE expression to iterate backward to get the previous month.

If you need to parametrize the amount of months you need to get modify the number of months (in this case it 120 for 10 years).

```
WITH List AS (
    SELECT
        DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) AS Start,
        DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) AS Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        DATEADD(MONTH, -1, Start),
        DATEADD(MONTH, -1, Date)
    FROM
        List 
    WHERE
        DATEDIFF(MONTH, Start, GETDATE()) < 120
)
SELECT
    Date
FROM
    List 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: Usual note that  a tally will *always* be more performant, especially so for larger ranges.

Comment: Without a physical table, a set-based CTE with a row constructor source and CROSS JOINs like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48776162/efficient-way-to-generate-2-billion-rows-in-sql-server-2014-developer) will perform much better than a recursive CTE for a large number of rows.