# Sql Select Top N and Include a Discrete Id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a query to bring back a subset of data for our business analysts to review. I received one id to test my query against but there are so many use cases I need to pull N records for them to review. What I would like to do is return a sample size of records but guarantee the single lonely id is included.

Example
I generate a list of numbers. I want to take the top 5 but the number 88 must be included in the result set.

```
DECLARE 
  @startnum INT=1,
  @endnum INT=100

;WITH gen AS (
    SELECT @startnum AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num+1 FROM gen WHERE num+1<=@endnum
)
SELECT * FROM gen
option (maxrecursion 100)

num
-----------
1
2
3
4
88
```

Is this possible?

By the way the above is from [Jayvee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21426929/2191098).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without `union all` by doing:

```
select top (5) g.*
from gen g
order by (case when num = 88 then 1 else 2 end), num;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/6428) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I marked this one because it it only has a single statement. By virtue of limiting the query results with the inclusion of a single value I am good with the order by and case performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like this:

```
DECLARE 
  @startnum INT=1,
  @endnum INT=100

;WITH gen AS (
    SELECT @startnum AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num+1 FROM gen WHERE num+1<=@endnum
)
SELECT TOP 4 * FROM gen WHERE num <> 88
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM gen WHERE num = 88
option (maxrecursion 100)
```