# While loop taking a long time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a loop that checks all the names and dates from `descript` column from table `tmp13` and stores them as individual rows in other table (`tmp14`). The problem is that the while loop is executing for a long time. I don't know how to make it run faster.

Here is my code checking the `descript` columns for names and date. `Descript` is a text column and can have multiple names and dates. I want to store those names and dates in separate rows.

```
DECLARE @Id INT
DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @product_num INT
DECLARE @REQUESTED VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @FirstDate VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @RequestedBy VARCHAR(255)

DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @date NVARCHAR(256)
DECLARE @desc NVARCHAR(256)

DECLARE @dateposition INT
DECLARE @nameposition INT
DECLARE @nameend INT

SELECT @count = MAX(id) 
FROM #TMP13

SET @id = 1;

WHILE (@id <= @count)
BEGIN
    SELCET @desc = descript FROM #TMP13 WHERE Id = @Id
    SELECT @product_num = p_Num FROM #TMP13 WHERE Id = @Id
    SELECT @REQUESTED = REQUESTED FROM #TMP13 WHERE Id = @Id
    SELECT @FirstDate = DATE1 FROM #TMP13 WHERE Id = @Id
    SELECT @RequestedBy = BY1 FROM #TMP13 WHERE Id = @Id


while (patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',@desc) > 0)
begin
    set @dateposition = patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9]%',@desc)
    set @date = SUBSTRING(@desc,@dateposition,10)

    set @nameposition = CHARINDEX('-', @desc)+2
    set @nameend = CHARINDEX(' ', @desc, @nameposition)+1
    set @name = SUBSTRING(@desc,@nameposition,@nameend-@nameposition)

    insert into #TMP14 
    values (@Id,@product_num,@REQUESTED, @FirstDate ,@RequestedBY, @date, @name)

    set @desc = SUBSTRING(@desc,@nameend,1024)  
end

set @id = @id + 1;

end

select * from #tmp14;
```

---sample table

```
CREATE TABLE #Tmp13(
p_Num             INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
REQUESTED          varchar(50),
DATE1            VARCHAR(50),   
BY1              VARCHAR(50),
DESCRIPT         TEXT
```

);

```
INSERT INTO #tmp13( p_Num , REQUESTED, DATE1, BY1 , DESCRIPT) VALUES 
(100,'John','5/30/2017','James','05/30/2017 12:25am Eastern Standard Time - 
Mjames reported changes in the pages 05/30/2017 10:35AM JRachael agreed to 
work on the report and report to James 05/30/2017 10:00 AM James reports 
errors in page.',NULL);

INSERT INTO Table_Tasks(WO_NUM,Opendate,ClosedDate,Note) VALUES 
(200,'John','6/1/2017','Rachael','06/1/2017 3:20PM Eastern Standard Time -  
Rsubramaniam reported phone is not functional 06/1/2017 4:00PM Service took 
the phone and replaced it with new one');

OUTPUT

 Id  product_num REQUESTED FirstDate  RequestedBY date         name    date  
                                                                        Name 

 1   100          John      5/30/2017  james      5/30/2017 mjames  5/30/2017 jRachael
```

Comment: What SQL are you using? MS MY other?

Comment: I am using Sql Server

Comment: The way to make this run faster is to stop using a loop when it isn't needed. This whole thing could be simplified to a single insert statement.

Comment: You do not have a loop, you have nested loops. This is a recipe for disaster. Please [edit] your question with sample data as DDL+DML and expected outout, so that we can show you a better way to get there.

Comment: "Descript is a text column and individual cell can have multiple names and dates" - Yet another terrible problem.

Comment: I will edit the question and add the expected and table format

Comment: You probably need to use 'Set Based' thinking instead of 'Procedural'.  This is a common problem for people who are somewhat new to SQL.

Comment: @Sam Are you sure?

Comment: I tried all the suggestion, and I am not very successful in getting the result. Can anyone please suggest some other way to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While loops will be slow because that's what happens when you use procedural logic to develop in a declarative programming language. For this you can use [patternSplitCM](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/String+Manipulation/94365/). There are issues with your sample data but this should get you what you need.

```
SELECT t.p_Num,
       t.REQUESTED,
       t.date1,
       t.BY1,
       parsedDate1 = MAX(CASE WHEN s.ItemNumber = 1 THEN s.Item END),
       parsedDate2 = MAX(CASE WHEN s.ItemNumber > 1 THEN s.Item END)
FROM   #Tmp13 AS t
CROSS 
APPLY    dbo.patternSplitCM(t.DESCRIPT, '[0-9/]') AS s
WHERE    s.[Matched] = 1 AND TRY_CAST(s.item AS DATE) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY t.p_Num,t.REQUESTED, t.date1,t.BY1
```

Results:

```
p_Num       REQUESTED    date1        BY1       parsedDate1  parsedDate2
----------- ------------ ------------ --------- ------------ ------------
100         John         5/30/2017    James     05/30/2017   05/30/2017
200         John         6/1/2017     Rachael   06/1/2017    06/1/2017
```

Lastly, for optimal performance you want an index on the columns p_Num,REQUESTED,DATE1,BY1 to support the GROUP BY clause. The index would look something like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX uq_xxx ON #Tmp13(p_Num,REQUESTED,DATE1,BY1) 
--INCLUDE (DESCRIPT); -- if you can change this to VARCHAR(8000) or VARCHAR(max)
```

Also note that this will likely run faster with a parallel execution plan. For that you can use TRACEFLAG 8649 or Adam Machanic's make_parallel().

Comment: Yeah I was trying to type fast and I might have missed something. This is really helpful, but I also want the name in the descript. How do I find that?

Comment: I adjusted the sample data table. Basically my main concern is when the descript reads 05/30/2017 12:25am Eastern Standard Time - 
Mjames I want the date  = 05/30/2017  and name = Mjames stored

Comment: I tried to use this way, but I have multiple names and date for each cell.  I have to find the dates manually this way since, I dont know how many dates I have.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the nested loops into two [CROSS JOINED](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php) SELECTS and use it to insert values. The overall structure will be be something like this

```
INSERT INTO #TMP14 
    (Id, product_num, REQUESTED, FirstDate , RequestedBY, date, name)
SELECT ...
CROSS JOIN
SELECT ...
```

Now you have to turn the outer loop which generates a sequence of numbers into one of these SELECT statements, and the inner loop which results from a string split into the other SELECT statements.

This SO question has several answers to the first problem: [How to generate a range of numbers between two numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425546/how-to-generate-a-range-of-numbers-between-two-numbers).

This SO question has answers to the second problem: [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows).

SQL-Server and database servers in general are highly optimized query engines, but are not very good in manipulating tables in loops.

Comment: I try this way. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Some speed improvements
set variables using single select instead of multiple select

```
SELCET @desc = descript,  @product_num = p_Num ,  @REQUESTED = REQUESTED  , @FirstDate = DATE1,  @RequestedBy = BY1  FROM #TMP13 WHERE Id = @Id
```

Remove Text data type (deprecated), use varchar(max)

```
CREATE TABLE #Tmp13(
p_Num             INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
REQUESTED          varchar(50),
DATE1            VARCHAR(50),   
BY1              VARCHAR(50),
DESCRIPT        varchar(max) --TEXT
);
```

Use varchar in place of nvarchar if possible.(@desc variable)

Do not repeat patindex call in loop

```
set @dateposition=999999--loop start
while (@dateposition > 0)
begin
    set @dateposition = patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9]%',@desc)
    if(@dateposition>0)begin
    ....
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I am will make those changes

Comment: @desc changes in the loop