# Generate data from 1 to specific value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am going to generate a result like this
suppose I have this records

```
Salah 3
John  2
```

I will expect this

```
Salah
Salah
Salah
John
John
```

Answer (score 1):

One method, if you always have a **small** value for *n* is to use a rCTE:

```sql
WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT [Name],
           N,
           1 AS I
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [Name],
           N,
           I + 1
    FROM rCTE
    WHERE I < N)
SELECT [Name]
FROM rCTe
ORDER BY [Name] DESC;
```

If you have much larger numbers, use a more performamt Tally. I use an inline here:

```sql
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT --TOP (SELECT MAX(N) FROM dbo.YourTable) --Limits the number of rows, which could also provide a performance benefit if you only sometimes have large numbers
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3) --1000 rows, add more cross joins for more rows
SELECT [Name]
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN Tally T ON YT.N >= T.I
ORDER BY YT.[Name] DESC;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f704b6b243dcb9a66a18f83fba6f177c)

Comment: Thank you. It was great

Comment: @Sali Be sure to ACCEPT Larnu's answer.   It is a small token of appreciation for his time and talent.   Also, it is an indicator to other contributors that the question has been answerd.

Comment: `1` looks gross, @Charlieface, how about `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

Having a permanent table of all positive integers (or at least as many as you realistically need) would let you have a very simple query, like:

```
select
    p.[Name]
from
    @People p
    inner join numbers on p.[Count] >= numbers.[Count]
order by
    p.[Name]
    ;
```

But if you don't want or can't have a table like that, you could use an approach like the one suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21425546/how-to-generate-a-range-of-numbers-between-two-numbers) to generate such a list on the fly, and use it like this:

```
declare @People table
(
    [Name] varchar(15),
    [Count] int
);

insert into @People
values
('Salah', 3),
('John', 2);

WITH x AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) v(n))

select
    p.[Name]
from
    @People p
    inner join
    (
        SELECT [Count] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
        FROM x ones, x tens, x hundreds, x thousands
    ) numbers on p.[Count] >= numbers.[Count]
order by
    p.[Name]
    ;
```